# Problems with blurring an image

Tags: arrays, c, struct, blur

I want to blur an image, by finding the neighbours of a pixel in the image, average the neighbours values and make the pixel that new value. Hence, the pixel is blured based on the surrounding pixels.

I have found other examples filled with if statements, which seems for me a bit hardcoded. I have tried to make my code as flexiable as possible, but without any luck. At this moment, I have done quite some research and tried different solutions without any luck.

Can you help me understand why it is not working. My last change is only yelling mistakes in : //Give new values to each color with the error: operand of type 'RGBTRIPLE' where arithmetic or pointer type is required.

But this error has something to do with how I structure my datatypes, but I think my real problem is around how I store my values in : //store values in xaxis and yaxis

Thank you!

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

//Int x and Int y used to identify how x and y should move around the pixel's axis
//Crete array for x and y axis 
int x[] = {-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1};
int y[] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};

//Counter to find the average.
int counter = 0;

//Variables for moving around the axis of pixel
int xaxis;
int yaxis;

//Creating my sum variable 
RGBTRIPLE sum;
sum = image[height][width];

// i and j should be maxium of 8, as we want to loop around neightbours, which is 8.
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
    
    //store values in xaxis and yaxis
    xaxis = height + x[i];
    yaxis = width + y[j];

    //If the pixel is in the corners
    if (xaxis < 0 || xaxis > x[i]-1 || yaxis < 0 || yaxis > y[j]-1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    
    //++ for counter
    counter++;
    
    //Store the values in pixel in sum
    sum = image[xaxis][yaxis];
    
    //Give new values to each color
    image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed + (int) sum;
    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (int) sum;
    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (int) sum;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        //Find the average
        int average = round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / counter);

        //Give pixel new value
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your average formula divide by 3 since you're adding 3 operands?

Comment: For one thing, the blur function should create a new image – your code is working with some pixels that have already been blurred. Also it should be based on 9 pixels (8 neighbours and the pixel itself) in the general area.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I see that now. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @jweyrich I believe not. As their can be 6 red colors around the image, which it should then be divided with. But I can see that there are some mistakes in that formula at this moment.

Comment: Yep. You're calculating the new value for each pixel only once. Currently you're using only 3 operands, so you should divide by 3. If you change it to sum the current pixel + N surrounding pixels, you divide by N+1.

Comment: Ah thank you! I see now! :)